# How to find the version of an installed package from a package-lock.json with lockfileVersion = 3

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, npm

I recently upgraded from Node 16 (which has npm 8) to Node 18 (which has npm 9). `package-lock.json` files generated with npm 8 have a `lockfileVersion: 2` whereas `package-lock.json` files generated with npm 9 have a `lockfileVersion: 3`. The differences are greater than that, however, and I've run into an issue trying to determine the version of a dependency by inspecting the `package-lock.json`.

Here is an example of JSON for a `package-lock.json` generated with npm 8:

```
{
  name: 'npm8 package',
  lockfileVersion: 2,
  packages: {
    '': {
      name: 'npm8 package',
      dependencies: {
        dependency1: '^1.2.3',
      },
    },
    "node_modules/dependency1": {
      "version": "1.2.8",
      "resolved": "https://someurl.com",
      "integrity": "sha512-blahblahblah"
    },
  },
  dependencies: {
    "dependency1": {
      "version": "1.2.8",
      "resolved": "https://someurl.com",
      "integrity": "sha512-blahblahblah"
    }
  },
}
```

Here is an example of JSON for a `package-lock.json` generated with npm 9:

```
{
  name: 'npm9 package',
  lockfileVersion: 3,
  packages: {
    '': {
      name: 'npm9 package',
      dependencies: {
        dependency1: '^1.2.3',
      },
    },
    "node_modules/dependency1": {
      "version": "1.2.8",
      "resolved": "https://someurl.com",
      "integrity": "sha512-blahblahblah"
    },
  }
}
```

As you can see, a `package-lock.json` file generated in npm 9 omits the `dependencies` node entirely.

My problem is that I was previously programmatically retrieving the version of an installed dependency by parsing the `package-lock.json` JSON and grabbing the version like this: `parsedPackageLockJSON.dependencies['dependency1'].version`. Now that does not exist and I'm unclear on how to get it from the `packages` node. `packages.dependencies['dependency1']` would only get me the version of the dependency from the `package.json`, not necessarily the installed version. The version I need appears to be at `packages.dependencies['node_modules/dependency1']`, but is it safe to prefix my dependency name with `node_modules/`?

ps. I understand I can get the installed version by running `npm ls --json`, but I need to do it using the `package-lock.json`. `npm ls` relies on the existence of the `node_modules` directory and, in my case, I'm trying to obtain the dependency version after programmatically cloning a repo. I don't want to also have to build the codebase so that the `node_modules` directory will exist so the `npm ls` command will work if the information *should* be available in the `package-lock.json` file.

Comment: "_I understand I can get the installed version by running `npm ls`, but I need to do it using the `package-lock.json`_": **Can you edit the question to include why?** The `npm ls` command [supports JSON-formatted output](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-ls?v=true#json) by using the `--json` argument, and will return a representation in a schema that works with the code you previously used.

Comment: @jsejcksn Updated.

Comment: There is a `package-lock-only` parameter for `npm ls` that works with only the lock file and ignores `node_modules`. Ref: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-ls#package-lock-only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments <sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77311802/how-to-find-the-version-of-an-installed-package-from-a-package-lock-json-with-lo#comment136296111_77311802), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77311802/how-to-find-the-version-of-an-installed-package-from-a-package-lock-json-with-lo#comment136296248_77311802)</sup>, `npm ls` supports additional arguments which can be used to produce JSON-formatted output in a schema that works with the code you previously used, and won't require installation of any dependencies:

> - [`json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-ls?v=true#json): (Default: *false*, Type: *Boolean*) Whether or not to output JSON data, rather than the normal output.
> - [`package-lock-only`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-ls?v=true#package-lock-only): (Default: *false*, Type: *Boolean*) If set to true, the current operation will only use the `package-lock.json`, ignoring `node_modules`. For `update` this means only the `package-lock.json` will be updated, instead of checking `node_modules` and downloading dependencies.  For `list` this means the output will be based on the tree described by the `package-lock.json`, rather than the contents of `node_modules`.

Below is a reproducible example to demonstrate.

---

Given a directory `so-77311802` whose only contents are the following 3 files:

```txt
so-77311802 % ls
package-lock.json       print_dependency_versions.mjs
package.json
```

`./package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "so-77311802",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "type": "module",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

`./package-lock.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "so-77311802",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 3,
  "requires": true,
  "packages": {
    "": {
      "name": "so-77311802",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "license": "MIT",
      "devDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "^20",
        "typescript": "^5"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/@types/node": {
      "version": "20.8.6",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/node/-/node-20.8.6.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-eWO4K2Ji70QzKUqRy6oyJWUeB7+g2cRagT3T/nxYibYcT4y2BDL8lqolRXjTHmkZCdJfIPaY73KbJAZmcryxTQ==",
      "dev": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "undici-types": "~5.25.1"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/typescript": {
      "version": "5.2.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript/-/typescript-5.2.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-mI4WrpHsbCIcwT9cF4FZvr80QUeKvsUsUvKDoR+X/7XHQH98xYD8YHZg7ANtz2GtZt/CBq2QJ0thkGJMHfqc1w==",
      "dev": true,
      "bin": {
        "tsc": "bin/tsc",
        "tsserver": "bin/tsserver"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=14.17"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/undici-types": {
      "version": "5.25.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/undici-types/-/undici-types-5.25.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-Ga1jfYwRn7+cP9v8auvEXN1rX3sWqlayd4HP7OKk4mZWylEmu3KzXDUGrQUN6Ol7qo1gPvB2e5gX6udnyEPgdA==",
      "dev": true
    }
  }
}
```

`./print_dependency_versions.mjs`:

```js
import { exec as execCb } from "node:child_process";
import { promisify } from "node:util";

const exec = promisify(execCb);

const npmLsOutput = JSON.parse(
  (await exec("npm ls --json --package-lock-only")).stdout,
);

for (const [name, { version }] of Object.entries(npmLsOutput.dependencies)) {
  console.log({ name, version });
}
```

---

Using `npm ls` with the arguments above produces this result in stdout:

```txt
so-77311802 % npm --version
9.8.1

so-77311802 % npm ls --json --package-lock-only
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "name": "so-77311802",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": {
      "version": "20.8.6",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/node/-/node-20.8.6.tgz",
      "overridden": false
    },
    "typescript": {
      "version": "5.2.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript/-/typescript-5.2.2.tgz",
      "overridden": false
    }
  }
}
```

Using Node.js to run the JavaScript module (which uses [`child_process.exec`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_processexeccommand-options-callback)) produces this output:

```txt
so-77311802 % node --version
v18.18.2

so-77311802 % node print_dependency_versions.mjs
{ name: '@types/node', version: '20.8.6' }
{ name: 'typescript', version: '5.2.2' }
```